# Отсутствие проверки данных на сервере PHP

Tags: php

Заинтересовал такой вот вопрос, на сколько такой кусок кода может представлять опасность?

```php
...
$email = $_POST["email"];
$success = mail("email@e.com", "title", "message", "From:".$email);
...
```

С SQL инъекциями все понятно, как и в инъекцией в `include`

P.S. Вопрос не о том, как проверить email на валидность, а о том в данной ситуации возможно ли использовать во вред отсутствие проверки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как сказали ранее, самое опасное что могут сделать - это спам. Как вариант, спам-боты.

Answer (score 0):

По-хорошему следовало бы проверить конечно самой простой регуляркой, которая просто чекает наличие собачки и точки в домене:

```
/.+@.+\..+/i
```

Этого достаточно в 99% ситуаций. И прикрутить запрет например не более 3 писем в минуту с одного IP. В таком вот акцепте.

С другой стороны, тип поля `<input type="email">` сделает львиную долю работы за тебя. В этом случае опасаться стоит только тех, кто откроет HTML в инспекторе и ручками поменяет тип поля, так что на бэке проверку я бы всё-же делал.

Comment: Это бредовая затея, лучше просто сам `mail` пихать в условие, да и вообще если пользователь неряха и не может удостоверится в правильности написания своего `email`, его проблемы, по этому в большинстве случаев проверку `email` делать не нужно.

Comment: @And проблема в том что исходя из вопроса чувак письмо шлёт не тому, кто мыло ввёл, а кому-то другому, указывая введённое мыло во `From:`.